# MetadataFileReference is inaccessible

Tags: c#, roslyn

I recently updated my project to Roslyn 1.0, and can't find MetadataFileReference class anywhere.

```
references: new[] { new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) }

Error   CS0122  'MetadataFileReference' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer in the source code:

```
references: new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly) }
```

Answer (score 9):

[MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs,ff3289acb1efc329) is obsolete

You should use [CreateFromFile](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs,ed274aef5ec6fd03) instead

```
       references: new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) }
```

Comment: Geez. Thank you, my friend. Good karma to you.